# Race condition in C Signal handler

Tags: c, linux, signals

I'm doing some coursework, and we've been presented with the following code. Some of the questions ask what various lines of the code do, which is fine, and I understand, but the curveball is "This program contains a race condition. Where and why does it arise?"

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

static void handler(int signo) { 
    printf("This is the SIGUSR1 signal handler!\n");
}

int main(void) { 
    sigset_t set;
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigset(SIGUSR1, handler);
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &set, NULL);

    while(1) {
        printf("This is main()!\n");
    }
    return 0;
```

}

I'm thinking along the lines that the race condition is that there is no way to know what order "This is main" or "This is the SIGUSR1" will be printed when the signal arrives, but if anyone could confirm or clarify this I'd much appreciate it. He also asks how it could be fixed (the race condition), not looking for a full answer but any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Something far worse can happen with the two `printf` statements...

Comment: to guarantee no races at all let the system set the signal masking for us before it calls the signal handler. This can be done if we use the sigaction() system call to define both the signal handler function AND the signal mask to be used when the handler is executed. You would probably be able to read the manual page for sigaction() on your own, now that you're familiar with the various concepts of signal handling. On old systems you won't find this system call, but you still might find the sigvec() call enables a similar functionality.
posted by jcomeau_ictx elsewhere, could this work here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the intent in the course is to modify the code to

- Use a separate thread, which receives the signals calling `sigwait()` or `sigwaitinfo()` in a loop. The signals must be blocked (first, and all along, for all threads), or the operation is unspecified (or the signals are delivered to the other thread).

  This way there is no signal handler function per se, which would be limited to async-signal safe functions. The thread that calls `sigwait()`/`sigwaitinfo()` is a perfectly normal thread, and not limited in any way related to signals or signal handlers.

  (There are other ways to receive the signals, for example using a signal handler which sets a global flag, and which the loop checks. Most of those lead to *busy-waiting*, running a do-nothing loop, burning CPU time uselessly: a very bad solution. The way I describe here squanders no CPU time: the kernel will put the thread to sleep when it calls `sigwait()`/`sigwaitinfo()`, and wakes it up only when a signal arrives. If you want to limit the duration of the sleep, you can use `sigtimedwait()` instead.)
- Since `printf()` et al. are not guaranteed to be thread-safe, you should probably use a `pthread_mutex_t` to protect output to standard output -- in other words, so that the two threads won't try to output at exactly the same time.

  In Linux this is not necessary, since GNU C `printf()` (except for the `_unlocked()` versions) is thread-safe; each call to these functions uses an internal mutex already.

  Note that the C library may cache outputs, so to make sure the data is output, you need to call `fflush(stdout);`.

  The mutex is especially useful, if you want to use multiple `printf()`, `fputs()`, or similar calls atomically, without the other thread being able to inject output in between. Therefore, the mutex is recommended even if on Linux in simple cases it is not required. (And yes, you do want to do the `fflush()` too while holding the mutex, although it may cause the mutex to be held for a long time if the output blocks.)

I'd personally solve the entire issue completely differently -- I'd use `write(STDERR_FILENO,)` in the signal handler to output to standard error, and have the main program output to standard output; no threads or anything special needed, just a simple low-level write loop in the signal handler. Strictly speaking, my program would behave differently, but to the end user the results look very much the same. (Except that one could redirect the outputs to different terminal windows, and look at them side-by-side; or redirect them to helper scripts/programs which prepend nanosecond wall-clock timestamps to each input line; and other similar tricks useful when investigating things.)

Personally, I found the jump from the original problem to the "correct solution" -- if indeed what I am describing is the correct solution; I do believe it is -- to be a bit of a stretch. This approach only dawned on me when Saf mentioned that the correct solution is expected to use pthreads.

I hope you find this informative, but not a spoiler.

---

Edited 2013-03-13:

Here is the `writefd()` function I use to safely write data from a signal handler to a descriptor. I also included the wrapper functions `wrout()` and `wrerr()` that you can use to write strings to standard output or standard error, respectively.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

/**
 * writefd() - A variant of write(2)
 *
 * This function returns 0 if the write was successful, and the nonzero
 * errno code otherwise, with errno itself kept unchanged.
 * This function is safe to use in a signal handler;
 * it is async-signal-safe, and keeps errno unchanged.
 *
 * Interrupts due to signal delivery are ignored.
 * This function does work with non-blocking sockets,
 * but it does a very inefficient busy-wait loop to do so.
*/
int writefd(const int descriptor, const void *const data, const size_t size)
{
    const char       *head = (const char *)data;
    const char *const tail = (const char *)data + size;
    ssize_t           bytes;
    int               saved_errno, retval;

    /* File descriptor -1 is always invalid. */
    if (descriptor == -1)
        return EINVAL;

    /* If there is nothing to write, return immediately. */
    if (size == 0)
        return 0;

    /* Save errno, so that it can be restored later on.
     * errno is a thread-local variable, meaning its value is
     * local to each thread, and is accessible only from the same thread.
     * If this function is called in an interrupt handler, this stores
     * the value of errno for the thread that was interrupted by the
     * signal delivery. If we restore the value before returning from
     * this function, all changes this function may do to errno
     * will be undetectable outside this function, due to thread-locality.
    */
    saved_errno = errno;

    while (head < tail) {

        bytes = write(descriptor, head, (size_t)(tail - head));

        if (bytes > (ssize_t)0) {
            head += bytes;

        } else
        if (bytes != (ssize_t)-1) {
            errno = saved_errno;
            return EIO;

        } else
        if (errno != EINTR && errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {
            /* EINTR, EAGAIN and EWOULDBLOCK cause the write to be
             * immediately retried. Everything else is an error. */
            retval = errno;
            errno = saved_errno;
            return retval;
        }
    }

    errno = saved_errno;
    return 0;
}

/**
 * wrout() - An async-signal-safe alternative to fputs(string, stdout)
 *
 * This function will write the specified string to standard output,
 * and return 0 if successful, or a nonzero errno error code otherwise.
 * errno itself is kept unchanged.
 *
 * You should not mix output to stdout and this function,
 * unless stdout is set to unbuffered.
 *
 * Unless standard output is a pipe and the string is at most PIPE_BUF
 * bytes long (PIPE_BUF >= 512), the write is not atomic.
 * This means that if you use this function in a signal handler,
 * or in multiple threads, the writes may be interspersed with each other.
*/
int wrout(const char *const string)
{
    if (string)
        return writefd(STDOUT_FILENO, string, strlen(string));
    else
        return 0;
}

/**
 * wrerr() - An async-signal-safe alternative to fputs(string, stderr)
 *
 * This function will write the specified string to standard error,
 * and return 0 if successful, or a nonzero errno error code otherwise.
 * errno itself is kept unchanged.
 *
 * You should not mix output to stderr and this function,
 * unless stderr is set to unbuffered.
 *
 * Unless standard error is a pipe and the string is at most PIPE_BUF
 * bytes long (PIPE_BUF >= 512), the write is not atomic.
 * This means that if you use this function in a signal handler,
 * or in multiple threads, the writes may be interspersed with each other.
*/
int wrerr(const char *const string)
{
    if (string)
        return writefd(STDERR_FILENO, string, strlen(string));
    else
        return 0;
}
```

If the file descriptor refers to a pipe, `writefd()` can be used to write up to `PIPE_BUF` (at least 512) bytes atomically.  `writefd()` can also be used in an I/O intensive application to convert signals (and if raised using `sigqueue()`, the related value, an integer or a pointer) to a socket or pipe output (data), making it much easier to multiplex multiple I/O streams and signal handling.  A variant (with an extra file descriptor marked close-on-exec) is often used to easily detect whether a child process executed another process, or failed; otherwise it is difficult to detect which process -- the original child, or the executed process -- exited.

In the comments to this answer, there was some discussion about `errno`, and confusion whether the fact that `write(2)` modifies `errno` makes it unsuitable for signal handlers.

First, POSIX.1-2008 (and earlier) defines [async-signal-safe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_27) functions as those that can safely be called from signal handlers. The [2.4.3 Signal actions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03) chapter includes a list of such functions, including `write()`. Note that it also explicitly states that *"Operations which obtain the value of errno and operations which assign a value to errno shall be async-signal-safe."*

That means that POSIX.1 intends `write()` to be safe to use in a signal handler, and that `errno` can also be manipulated to avoid the interrupted thread seeing unexpected changes in `errno`.

Because `errno` is a thread-local variable, each thread has their own `errno`. When a signal is delivered, it always interrupts one of the existing threads in the process. Signals can be directed to a specific thread, but usually the kernel decides which thread gets a process-wide signal; it varies between systems. If there is only one thread, the initial or main thread, then obviously it is the one that gets interrupted. All this means that if the signal handler saves the value of `errno` it initially sees, and restores it just before it returns, the changes to `errno` are invisible outside the signal handler.

There is one way to *detect* it, though, also hinted at in POSIX.1-2008 by the careful wording:

Technically, `&errno` is almost always valid (depending on system, compiler, and standards applied), and yields the address of the `int` variable holding the error code for the current thread. It is therefore possible for another thread to monitor the error code of another thread, and yes, this thread would see the changes to it done within the signal handler. However, there is no guarantee that the other thread is able to access the error code atomically (although it is atomic on many architectures): such "monitoring" would be informative only anyway.

It is a pity that almost all signal handler examples in C use stdio.h `printf()` et cetera. Not only is it wrong on many levels -- from non-async-safe to the caching issues, possibly non-atomic accesses to `FILE` fields, if the interrupted code was also doing I/O at the same time --, but the *correct* solution using `unistd.h` similar to my example in this edit is just as simple. The rationale for using stdio.h I/O in signal handlers seems to be "it usually works". I detest that, personally, since for example violence also "usually works". I consider it stupid and/or lazy.

I hope you found this informative.

Comment: That's an excellent explanation, and give me a lot of information on some of the other related work I still have to do - thank you very much. I'll link or post the solution when I get it done.

Comment: @JulienPalard: Poppycock, of course you can. `errno` is a per-thread variable. All you need to do is save the value of `errno` before any `write()` calls (and any other async-signal-safe calls that modify `errno` you might use), then restore it before returning from the signal handler. Oh, and thanks for the downvote based on incorrect information/assumption.

Comment: @NominalAnimal I'll downvote you twice if I could. Being thread-safe is not the same as being signal-safe, and here the question is about signals, not thread, please review POSIX chapter 3.3.1.3. Please stop spreading wrong informations based on incorrect assumption.

Comment: @JulienPalard: You are either a troll, or an idiot. `write()` is an *async-signal-safe* function, explicitly listed safe to use in a signal handler. If an error occurs, `write()` does modify `errno`. Because `errno` is a thread-local variable, that change is only visible to the thread the signal delivery interrupted. Restoring `errno` in the signal handler to the value it had at the beginning of the signal handler makes any change to `errno` undetectable outside the signal handler. Read IEEE 1003.1-2008 3.2.7 Async-signal-safe, and 2.4.3 Signal actions, and realize you're utterly wrong.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Ok, TIL that write is listed in the Async-signal-safe list of functions in "POSIX.1-2004", upvoting you again, and sorry !

Comment: @JulienPalard: That's okay; I'm just *very* prickly when my knowledge is questioned, and I do have quite a lot of experience with this type (low-level I/O, signals, syscalls and their effects) of C code in Linux. If you think it is informative to others, I could append the `write()` wrapper code I use and its rationale to my answer?

Comment: @NominalAnimal I too jump high when I see wrong thins on a topic, but today I leart something, and that's cool too :-). Append it if you want, it may help someone. (Can't upvote you til you change your answer, so if you do, i'll be able to upvote you)

Comment: @JulienPalard: I appended the function I normally use. Not for the vote, but in case the explanation and context helps others. However, I'm not that precise with standards (I rely more on actual behaviour in Linux, on kernel and C library documentation), so feel free to point out any problems in my edit -- there might be logical leaps or omitted references that I should add or fill in.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Do you also use your wrapper outside of signal handlers ? Seems strange, to me, to backup errno outside of handlers, what about this ? (re-upvoted)

Comment: @JulienPalard: Yes, but normally only in error and debugging code paths. It may seem strange, but it is robust: `errno` will propagate the correct value properly to the caller, automatically. In normal code paths I do not backup `errno`, I just zero it prior to calling a function. If the function returns a failure, I check `errno`. (A lot of libraries are badly written, and may modify `errno` even if no error occurs. Typical case is `errno==EINTR`.) Note that POSIX.1 recommends explicitly zeroing `errno` before calling a function that may fail, if `errno` is examined in the error cases.

Comment: @NominalAnimal TIL (thanks) that POSIX, you're right, states that "An application that needs to examine the value of errno to determine the error should set it to 0 [...].". I don't understand excatly why, as if a function an error, errno will be set by the called function, leading to double affectation of errno, so first affectation, of 0, is completly useless. The only usefull way to set errno to 0 is to focus on errno and not function return value to check for the success of the call, a strange behavior, no ? (And let's examine the performance of reading errno instead of eax...)

Comment: @JulienPalard: Consider `strtol(3)` converting `LONG_MIN` or `LONG_MAX`. Unless you clear `errno` first, you cannot tell whether the `LONG_MIN` or `LONG_MAX` return value was an error or just a valid result of the conversion. Some `malloc()` implementations sometimes forget to set `errno` when they return `NULL`, and so on. Very few functions really need errno cleared.. it is just a defensive technique to shield against library bugs and logic errors -- POSIX says *should*, not *must*. Also, POSIX says you cannot rely on `errno` alone; check `errno` only if the function indicated an error.

Answer (score 7):

There is really no race condition; it is worse than that. According to the POSIX standard, *the behaviour of the program is undefined* (if the signal is delivered at the right moment).

Look at [man 7 signal](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html) man page, specifically the section under *Async-signal safe functions*:

> A signal handler function must be very careful, since processing
>   elsewhere may be interrupted at some arbitrary point in the execution
>   of the program.  POSIX has the concept of "safe function".  If a
>   signal interrupts the execution of an unsafe function, and handler
>   calls an unsafe function, then the behavior of the program is
>   undefined.

Note that `printf()` is definitely not an *async-signal safe function*; therefore the behaviour is undefined.

In a general case, the solution is nontrivial, because there are no async-signal safe locking primitives (other than `sem_post()`, which by itself is not enough for this, and file locks, which would have to be used around all `printf()` calls). The generic, portable solution is to create a pipe using `pipe()` from `unistd.h`, and write the output to the pipe using `write()`, and have the main program read from the pipe and "forward" the contents. POSIX quarantees that writes shorter than `PIPE_BUF` are atomic, with `PIPE_BUF` being at least 512 (4096 in Linux) -- see [`man 7 pipe`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pipe.7.html) for details --, so this is also limited to 512-byte or shorter messages in practice for portable code.

Commonly, and in this particular case, it is enough to replace the `printf()` in the signal handler with setting a global `volatile sigatomic_t` variable. The main loop can then simply check (and clear) the global variable and output the message itself.

While the flag variable approach can lose rapidly repeated `SIGUSR1` signals, it is irrelevant because you can *always*  lose rapidly repeated `SIGUSR1` signals: only one can be pending at a time, so repeated signals occurring between the first one and when it is handled, are not delivered at all! (If you were to use realtime signals like `SIGRTMIN+0` which are queued, you can make sure you catch every single one by using atomic built-ins like `__sync_fetch_and_and(variable,0)` or `__atomic_exchange_n(variable,0,__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)` in the main loop, and `__sync_fetch_and_add(variable,1)` or `__atomic_fetch_add(variable,1,__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)` in the signal handler; both preceded by a `__sync_synchronize()` or `__atomic_signal_fence(__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)` call to make sure the changes are immediately effective/visible to the other. But you don't need to worry about atomic ops in this case.)

There is an interesting corner case -- not a race condition -- with respect to `sigset()` and `sigprocmask()`, too. A process inherits its signal mask from its parent, with `SIGUSR1` not blocked by default. Unless handled, it causes the process to terminate. Therefore, depending on the inherited signal mask, a `SIGUSR1` signal delivered before the `sigset()` call is either blocked, or causes the process to terminate. (However, if `set` contained `SIGUSR1`; i.e. `SIGUSR1` was blocked, then there *would* be a race condition, unless `sigprocmask()` was called before `sigset()`. However, since `set` is empty, `sigset()` is best called before `sigprocmask()`.)

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer. It seems we have to implement the solution using posix pthreads, but everything I've read suggests mixing the two (signals & pthreads) is a terrible idea. Any advice on this? I'll try to work it out and maybe post the code if I can't get it to work.

Comment: @Saf: There are a lot of techniques for mixing signals and pthreads.  You **do** have to be careful, but some simple techniques can make the whole thing simple.  For example, since `write` (**NOT** `fwrite`) is async-safe you can send messages from signal handlers through pipes or Unix domain sockets.

Comment: I've not run into any major issues in Linux; I use `man 7 signal` as a reference. Signal handlers are assigned per process, so all threads will always have the same handlers, but signals can be directed to specific threads. You may need to block signals using `pthread_sigmask()` if it is to be delivered to a specific thread; otherwise the kernel will pick "at random" which thread will receive the signal. In complex cases you can use a reflector, a handler which forwards the signal (changing the signal number to say `SIGRTMIN+1`) to thread using `pthread_sigqueue()`.

Comment: @Saf: In this case, block `SIGUSR1` for the entire process (all threads), and call `sigwait()` in a loop in a dedicated thread to receive the signals. GNU C pthreads are thread-safe, so you can use `printf()` et al to output to standard output from all threads. Use `fflush(stdout);` to make sure the `printf()`s are not cached by the C library.

If you want to show off, install a `SIGINT` handler which sets a global `volatile sig_atomic_t` variable to zero. Initialize it to one, and have threads loop until it becomes zero, then clean up and exit. Then, Ctrl+C stops your program **cleanly**.